# Shaft Nominal Diameter for M16 thread

Tags: machining, threads, bolting

I am looking to machine a M16 thread with a pitch of 2mm on a shaft, but I am unsure about what diameter should that shaft be in order to achieve the desired M16 thread. Does this change depending on the standard used to create the pitch (between a ISO standard or a DIN standard?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Short answer, nominal diameter = 16 mm. Many places to get more detailed specs, such as: https://international.optimas.com/technical-resources/metric-thread-dimensions/ Pretty sure ISO and DIN standards are essentially identical.